# Can I add WebApi to an ASP.NET 5 (vnext) project without MVC6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've got a vanilla html/javascript site and I am ready to add some WebApi stuff. In asp.net 4 I would simply add WebApi from NuGet and I could start adding ApiControllers that inherit from ApiController (after a little setup in the Global file).

I tried this in an ASP.NET 5 (vnext) project and it didn't work. While adding `using System.Web.Http;` did get rid o the squiggley under `ApiController` in my class:

```
[Route("api/contact/requestACall")]
public class ContactController : ApiController
{
}
```

...I still got errors when trying to compile.

`Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Route' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [my namespace].DNX Core 5.0 [my project path]\Controllers\ContactController.cs  5`

`Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ApiController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [my namespace].DNX Core 5.0 [my project path]\Controllers\ContactController.cs  6`

I've googled for hours and every walkthrough I can find is adding MVC6 in order to add api controllers. However, I don't need any MVC functionality in this site, since I am using angular and doing all that on the client.

How can I use WebApi without bringing all this MVC baggage with me? I know the whole point of ASP.NET 5 was to make sure you never had to include stuff you weren't going to use, so I am sure I am missing something.

Comment: It's not MVC "baggage" in the sense that you're used to.  In vNext/ASP.NET 5, both frameworks have been consolidated into a single, streamlined API that takes the best of both.  In the past it may have been worth it leave MVC behind but this is a bold new world and it takes a new way of thinking.  The old rules no longer apply :)

Comment: Are you saying WebApi cannot be used alone? Can you say this definitively? I wonder why even have separate packages then.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc  The documentation for the source clearly describes this particular branch as: Model view controller framework for building dynamic web sites with clean separation of concerns, including the merged MVC, Web API, and Web Pages w/ Razor.  My interpretation of this is that yes, they are completely merged and cannot and should not be separated under vNext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot.  Multiple frameworks have been combined in vNext.

The documentation for the [ASP.NET MVC](http://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) source clearly describes this particular branch as: Model view controller framework for building dynamic web sites with clean separation of concerns, including the merged MVC, Web API, and Web Pages w/ Razor. My interpretation of this is that yes, they are completely merged and cannot and should not be separated under vNext.

In addition, if you look at the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/ApiController.cs) for `ApiController` in vNext, you'll find that the following references are included:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ActionResults;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Actions;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim;
```

This makes it impossible to use `ApiController` without the core MVC dependencies in ASP.NET 5.

In light of the comments, if you look at this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6), you'll find that "WebAPI" controllers (controllers who's primary responsibility is to return api data instead of web content) inherits from `Controller`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
...
Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TodoController : Controller
```

In summary, in vNext, there is only one controller that you should be using regardless of the type of content being delivered, `Controller`, and it should ***only*** come from `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`.

`System.Web.Http` is deprecated and `Microsoft.AspNet.WebAPI` is not used whatsoever in vNext.

Comment: If webapi depends on mvc, then why doesn't the webapi package depend on the mvc package? Also, the source you linked isn't the class I tried to use. I tried to use System.Web.Http.ApiController. Looks like it's an abstract class and that is my issue, but there may still be some web api controller that inherits from it.

Comment: Also, I just found this out. If you create a new vNext mvc project, it will include Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, but not Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi! So is Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi strictly a legacy package?

Comment: @Chris To clear up some confusion, you shouldn't be using `System.Web.Http.ApiController` in vNext.  That **is** legacy code.  I believe that `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` is not necessarily a legacy package, but that it is non-compatible with vNext (but it would work with 4.6 if you were continuing to build a site outside of 5), although I am not 100% certain of that.  But yes, the ***core*** dependencies for vNext controllers are in `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` and that is the only package you should focus on using.

Comment: It's looking like you are correct, and I will mark this answer as correct when I am more sure. It just seems so odd that they would endeavor to separate concerns and then bundle mvc with web api as a means to achieve that, you know? At this point maybe I'm just reaching for a "yeah, that does seem a little weird" but you don't need to give that to me to get an accepted answer. I promise I'd give it either way =)

Comment: Well, if you look at the entire ecosystem as a whole, they revamped many touchpoints so that you could pull in what you need when you need it.  However, with MVC and WebAPI they noticed that there was a ton of similarities with a few very frustrating differences, which is why they flattened it out into a single, purposeful API.  David Fowler had a good blog post months ago that helps explain a few of their decisions: http://davidfowl.com/asp-net-vnext-architecture/

Comment: Also, a previous post, http://davidfowl.com/asp-net-vnext/, presented the same issue as something they wanted to fix: Web API and MVC were different but had very similar programming models. Occasionally people would get confused about what to pick and when to pick it. It even sparked some debate among the ASP.NET community